# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'board_topics' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django

i am struggling with this error, please any help,
i tried many solution for this error but nothing work

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from .models import Board
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    boards = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'boards':boards})

def board_topics(request,board_id):
    # try:
    #     board = Board.objects.get(pk=board_id)
    # except:
    #     raise Http404
    board = get_object_or_404(Board,pk=board_id)
    return render(request,'topics.html',{'board':board})

def new_topic(request,board_id):
    return render(request,'new_topic.html')

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse(request,'yes')
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('about/',views.about,name='about'),
    path('boards/<int:board_id>/', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
    path('boards/<int:board_id>/new/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic')
]
```

new_topic.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} creat new topic {% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"> <a href="{% url 'home'%}"> Boards </a> </li> 
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}"> {{board.name}} </a> </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New Topic</li>
{% endblock %}
```

Usually I could easily read where the error is coming from and deal with it but in this case I can't spot the cause of the error hence I'm unable to progress with my study. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass `{'board':board}` from `new_topic` view to the template the same way you do in `board_topics`. Currently `board` is not initialized in `new_topic` template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell it what `board_id` is, since that's what you have in your URL.

```
 <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board_id=board.pk %}"> {{board.name}} </a> </li>
```